# Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined. Am I not publishing correctly?

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, publish-subscribe, undefined-behavior

My app was working perfectly till I externalized the collection definition from the `client/main.js` file to the `../imports/api/tasks.js` file.

After this move I keep getting this error message in my browser: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined`in my browser console. This error message points to line `main.js:1206` which is:

/myApp
../client/main.js

```
import { Images } from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
Meteor.subscribe('Images');

FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
var teste = Images.insert(file,  function (err, fileObj) {

var insertedIdSession = teste._id;
session.set("insertedBuyId", insertedIdSession);
Images.find().count());

  });
```

/myApp 
../imports/api/tasks.js

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})] });
```

/myApp
../server/main.js

```
import { Images } from '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Meteor.publish('Images', function(){
return Images.find();
});
```

I have researched but failed to find a solution for this. Kind point out where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that "Images" is not defined.

From what I can see of your code, ../imports/api/tasks.js does not export anything, which means that

```
import { Images } from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

won't give you anything, in fact it will replace the global variable Images with a null. So I think the solution is to replace the imports with this:

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

Or you can put tasks.js in /common and that will do the same job

Comment: Thanks, I used your latter solution `import '../imports/api/tasks.js';` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your `Images` collection in order to import it to other files, like this:

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";

export const Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```